# Help needed in deducing an inequality in a research paper in additive number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisor-counting-function, goldbachs-conjecture

I need help in proving this inequality->

> Assuming q to be any positive integer prove that ( 1+ log(q) )  d(q) $\phi^{-2} (q) $ $\leq$ $ q^{-5/3}$ . where d(q) means number of divsor of q and $\phi(q) $ = number of integer less than q which are co-prime to q.

[image]

I am unable to deduce (39) on page 6 of research paper and this inequality will be used there. The motive of asking the question and putting the bounty is to prove (39) .I hope that I am not wrong in thinking that the above mentioned inequality will lead to proving (39) ?

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why he downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality asked for is equivalent to $\phi(n) \geq cn^{5/6}\sqrt{d(n)\log n}$ and this follows from known estimates on $\phi(n)$ and $d(n)$. For example, $\phi(n)$ is asymptotically at least $\dfrac{n}{\log \log n}$, whereas the divisor function is (asymptotically) upper-bounded by $n^{\epsilon}$ for every $\epsilon>0$. The required bound also follows from $\varphi(n)d(n) \geq cn^2$.

For proofs of the three bounds stated above, see: [Lower bound for $\phi(n)$: Is $n/5 < \phi (n) < n$ for all $n > 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101654/lower-bound-for-phin-is-n-5-phi-n-n-for-all-n-1?rq=1) and https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/
and [Lower bound of Euler phi function times sum of divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061349/lower-bound-of-euler-phi-function-times-sum-of-divisors?rq=1)

Comment: my inequality is $\phi_(q) \geq q^{5/6} {(d(q) +d(q) log(q) ) }^{0.5}$ how is that equivalent to your identity, I don't get it? Can you please explain?

Comment: Because $\sqrt{d(n)+d(n)\log n)}=\Theta(\sqrt{d(n)\log n})$.

Comment: I think this should be used -> d(n) = o$ ( n^{\delta} ) $ for every $\delta$ >0 . So, LHS  n / loglog(n) >0 and on RHS and $\epsilon $ tending to 0 come s due to small o notation. So, LHS always greater than or equal to LHS. Am I right? Can you please verify?

Comment: Yes, you are right, $d(n)=o(n^{\delta})$ for every $\delta>0$, and we need to use that.

Comment: did you got bounty points?

Comment: did you got bounty? can you reply?

Comment: I think you have!!